# InfiniteScroll doesn't call loadMore handler, even if hasMore prop is true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to make a list with infinite scroll feature by using react-infinite-scroll-component.
The problem is that it doesn't work when I scroll down to the end of the list. It doesn't call loadMore function in property next={loadMore} even when I hardcoded hasMore={true}
So, nothing happens when I scroll down the list.

Here is an example of my code:

```
    const {
                setTotalItemsCount,
                // hasMore,
                loadMore,
                rowsPerPage,
                currentPage,
                addItems,
                items: accountLedgerItems,
                reset: resetInfiniteScroll,
              } = useInfiniteScroll({ rowsPerPage: 20 });
        
        const {
            loading: accountLedgerLoading,
            error: accountLedgerError,
            data: accountLedgerData,
            refetch: refetchListAccountLedgerQuery,
          } = useQueryCustomApolloClient(
            ListAccountLedgerQuery, {
              variables: {
                input: {
                  accountId: account.id,
                  filterParams,
                  paginationParams: {
                    limit: rowsPerPage,
                    offset: currentPage * (rowsPerPage || 0),
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          );
    
    const refetchListAccountLedger = async () => {
        resetInfiniteScroll();
        await sleep(50);
        await refetchListAccountLedgerQuery();
      };
    
      useEffect(async () => {
        await refetchListAccountLedgerQuery();
      }, [currentPage]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (accountLedgerError !== undefined) {
      enqueueSnackbar(accountLedgerError.message, {
        variant: 'error',
      });
    }

    if (!accountLedgerData) return;

    const items = [...accountLedgerData.listAccountLedger.items].reverse();
    addItems(items);
    setTotalItemsCount(accountLedgerData.listAccountLedger.count);
  }, [accountLedgerData]);
    
            
            ...
    
            
                <div ref={refLedgerContainer} style={{ height: 500, overflow: 'auto' }} id="scrollableDiv">
                        <InfiniteScroll
                          dataLength={accountLedgerItems.length}
                          hasMore
                          next={loadMore}
                          loader={<LinearProgress />}
                          endMessage={<><hr /></>}
                          inverse
                          height={500}
                          scrollableTarget="scrollableDiv"
                        >
                          {getRows(accountLedgerItems)}
                        </InfiniteScroll>
                </div>
```

Here is useInfiniteScroll component:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const useInfiniteScroll = ({ rowsPerPage = 20, defaultCurrentPage = 0 }) => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(defaultCurrentPage);
  const [totalItemsCount, setTotalItemsCount] = useState(0);
  const loadMore = () => {
    setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
  };
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const hasMore = () => ((currentPage + 1) * rowsPerPage) < totalItemsCount;
  const reset = () => {
    setItems([]);
    setTotalItemsCount(0);
    setCurrentPage(defaultCurrentPage);
  };
  const addItems = (newItems) => {
    setItems((prevItems) => [...prevItems, ...newItems]);
  };
  return {
    rowsPerPage,
    currentPage,
    totalItemsCount,
    setTotalItemsCount,
    loadMore,
    hasMore: hasMore(),
    items,
    dataLength: items.length,
    addItems,
    reset,
  };
};

export default useInfiniteScroll;
```